How to pass correct URL for SetUp Intent on Stripe for subscriptions
Hello am getting this error when i try to create a subscription to my Ionic 5 angular 14, capacitor 5 project
Setup Intent: {id: 'seti_1Pej4HGozbMWFnur4OWfvqdA', object: 'setup_intent', automatic_payment_methods: {…}, cancellation_reason: null, client_secret: 'seti_1Pej4HGozbMWFnur4OWfvqdA_secret_QVkZdP11j4gFm56rj95UypBo3PHvYU8', …}
subscription.page.ts:127 Setup Intent ID: seti_1Pej4HGozbMWFnur4OWfvqdA
subscription.page.ts:128 Payment Method: pm_1Pej4lGozbMWFnurI7EVBUxj
subscription.page.ts:140 Subscribing with Payment Method ID: pm_1Pej4lGozbMWFnurI7EVBUxj
subscription.page.ts:141 Subscribing with SetupIntent ID: seti_1Pej4HGozbMWFnur4OWfvqdA
subscription.page.ts:149 Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\SetupIntent instance has invalid ID: 

in this component code
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserData } from 'src/app/services/user-data/user-data';
import { loadStripe, Stripe, StripeElements, StripeElementsOptions, PaymentMethod } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscription',
  templateUrl: 'subscription.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['subscription.page.scss'],
})
export class SubscriptionPage implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('paymentElement') paymentElementRef: ElementRef;
  stripe: Stripe;
  elements: StripeElements;
  clientSecret: string;
  planId = 'price_1OPuphGozbMWFnudfddsfgh';
  customerId: any;
  isPaymentElementFilled: boolean = false;

  appearance: StripeElementsOptions['appearance'] = {
    theme: 'stripe',
    variables: {
      colorPrimary: '#0570de',
      colorBackground: '#ffffff',
      colorText: '#30313d',
      colorDanger: '#df1b41',
      fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif',
      spacingUnit: '2px',
      borderRadius: '4px',
    },
  };

  user: any = {};
  email: string = '';
  uid: string = '';
  paymentMethod: string | PaymentMethod;
  menuOpenCopyright: boolean = false;

  modalOpen: boolean = false;
  cardInputFocused: boolean = false;

  constructor(public router: Router, public userData: UserData) {
    this.user = this.userData.getUserData();
    this.uid = this.user.uid;
    this.email = this.user.email;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createCustomerAndSetupIntent();
  }

  createCustomerAndSetupIntent() {
    this.userData.createCustomer(this.email).subscribe((customerResponse: any) => {
      if (customerResponse.success) {
        this.customerId = customerResponse.customer.id;
        this.userData.createSetupIntent(this.customerId).subscribe((setupIntentResponse: any) => {
          if (setupIntentResponse.success) {
            this.clientSecret = setupIntentResponse.setupIntent.client_secret;
            console.log('Client Secret:', this.clientSecret);

            this.initializeStripe().then(() => {
              this.createPaymentElement(this.clientSecret);
            }).catch(error => {
              console.error('Error initializing Stripe:', error);
            });
          } else {
            console.error(setupIntentResponse.error);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error(customerResponse.error);
      }
    });
  }

  async initializeStripe() {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_51HiSUoGozbMWFnurWW3azSXFZV47mcnH8p4MQG6HvbHuszrDPvUFYuq15TbVqZujcJNv4CSHSqkAkFm3pRk7nwod00iHfdert');
    this.stripe = await stripePromise;
  }

  createPaymentElement(clientSecret: string) {
    if (!this.stripe) {
      console.error('Stripe is not initialized.');
      return;
    }

    this.elements = this.stripe.elements({
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      appearance: this.appearance,
    });

    const paymentElementOptions = {};

    const paymentElement = this.elements.create('payment', paymentElementOptions);

    paymentElement.on('change', (event) => {
      this.isPaymentElementFilled = event.complete;
    });

    paymentElement.mount(this.paymentElementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  async confirmPayment() {
    const result: any = await this.stripe.confirmSetup({
      elements: this.elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: window.location.href,
        payment_method_data: {
          billing_details: {
            email: this.email,
          },
        },
      },
      redirect: 'if_required' // Disable automatic redirection
    });

    console.log('Setup Intent:', result.setupIntent);

    if (result.error) {
      console.error(result.error);
    } else if (result.setupIntent) {
      const setupIntent = result.setupIntent;
      if (setupIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
        const paymentMethod = setupIntent.payment_method;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
        console.log('Setup Intent ID:', setupIntent.id); // Log setupIntent ID
        console.log('Payment Method:', paymentMethod); // Log payment method
        this.subscribe(paymentMethod, setupIntent.id);
      } else {
        console.error('Setup Intent not succeeded:', setupIntent);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected result structure:', result);
    }
  }

  async subscribe(paymentMethod: string | PaymentMethod, setupIntentId: string) {
    const paymentMethodId = typeof paymentMethod === 'string' ? paymentMethod : paymentMethod.id;
    console.log('Subscribing with Payment Method ID:', paymentMethodId); // Log payment method ID
    console.log('Subscribing with SetupIntent ID:', setupIntentId); // Log setupIntent ID

    this.userData.createSubscription(this.customerId, this.planId, setupIntentId).subscribe((subscriptionResponse: any) => {
      if (subscriptionResponse.success) {
        console.log('Subscription successful:', subscriptionResponse.subscription);
        this.showSubscriptionSuccess();
        this.router.navigate(['app/tablinks/home']);
      } else {
        console.error(subscriptionResponse.error);
      }
    });
  }




  showSubscriptionSuccess() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Subscription Successful',
      text: 'Your subscription has been successfully created.',
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    });
  }

user-data functions
createCustomer(email: string): Observable<any> {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createCustomer';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
          api_signature: this.api_signature,
          email: email,
        });
    
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options.headers });
      }
    
      createSetupIntent(customerId: string): Observable<any> {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createSetupIntent';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
          customerId: customerId,
        });
    
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options.headers });
      }
    
      createSubscription(customerId: string, planId: string, setupIntentId: string): Observable<any> {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createSubscription';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            customerId: customerId,
            planId: planId,
            setupIntentId: setupIntentId
        });
    
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options.headers });
    } 

php functions
  function createCustomer() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true;

    $userEmail = $request->post('email');

    try {
        // Create a new Stripe customer
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
            'email' => $userEmail,
        ]);

        $userStripeCustomerId = $customer->id;

        // Update the user record in the database with the Stripe customer ID
        $db = getDB();
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET customer_id = :customer_id WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":customer_id", $userStripeCustomerId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $userEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $response = [
            'customer' => $customer,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}

function createSetupIntent() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true;

    $customerId = $request->post('customerId');

    try {
        // Create a SetupIntent for the given customer
        $setupIntent = \Stripe\SetupIntent::create([
            'customer' => $customerId,
        ]);
        $clientSecret = $setupIntent->client_secret;

        $response = [
            'setupIntent' => $setupIntent,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}


function createSubscription() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response = ['success' => true];

    $customerId = $request->post('customerId');
    $planId = $request->post('planId');
    $setupIntentId = $request->post('setupIntentId'); // Receiving setupIntentId from frontend

    // Log received setupIntentId
    error_log("Received setupIntentId: " . $setupIntentId);

    try {
        // Retrieve the SetupIntent using the setupIntentId
        $setupIntent = \Stripe\SetupIntent::retrieve($setupIntentId);
        
        // Log the retrieved setupIntent
        error_log("Retrieved SetupIntent: " . print_r($setupIntent, true));

        if ($setupIntent->status !== 'succeeded') {
            throw new \Exception("SetupIntent is not succeeded.");
        }

        $paymentMethod = $setupIntent->payment_method;

        // Create a subscription for the customer with the specified plan
        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
            'customer' => $customerId,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'price' => $planId,
                ],
            ],
            'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethod,
        ]);

        $response = [
            'subscription' => $subscription,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
        // Log Stripe API errors
        error_log("Stripe API error: " . $e->getMessage());
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Log general exceptions
        error_log("General error: " . $e->getMessage());
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}

It looks like the issue stems from how the setupIntentId and paymentMethodId are being used in the subscription creation process. The error message "Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\SetupIntent instance has invalid ID" suggests that there's a problem with the ID being passed. How do i fix that? Is a problem with the code or i have to do some implementation in Stripe dashboard?
Can you give me any help? Thanks

Can you clarify exactly which line of code is returning that error? Is it this.userData.createSubscription() or something else?

Also, if your goal is to create a Subscription, you shouldn't create a SetupIntent. Instead create a Subscription, and then use the PaymentIntent/SetupIntent created by the Subscription. This is explained in details here.

That exact exception will happen from $setupIntent = \Stripe\SetupIntent::retrieve($setupIntentId); if $setupIntentId is null/empty string, so that's where you need to focus debugging.
